# Why is the output of `j= ++i + ++i;` different in C# and C?

Tags: c#, c, pre-increment

```
int i=1,j;
j= ++i + ++i;
printf("%d",j);
```

The output of this program is `6` in C.But when I use the same logic for C#,
the output is `5` .

I want to know the reason why the same logic behaves differently in two different languages

Comment: Undefined behavior means: 5 is 6. So the output is the same :) (You cannot change `i` twice without a _sequence point_ in between in C)

Comment: You mean the output is 6 in *your* C compiler.  other answers are available because it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Probably because they're not the "same logic."

Comment: It doesn't really matter either way.  Only a total idiot would use such constructs in real code.

Comment: Just curious.. Did you do any research regarding this prior to asking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rule in C# is "**evaluate each subexpression strictly left to right**". Therefore

```
j= ++i + ++i ;
```

is **well defined in C#** but the same expression invokes [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C because you can't modify a variable more than once between two [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

[C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html):

> The Standard states that
>
> **Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression**. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.)

Read this article by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) for further explanation: [Precedence vs Associativity vs Order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: does increment//decrement  operator not evaluate from right to left?

Comment: Do you mean expressions ?

Comment: In C order of evaluation of expressions is not guaranteed.