# What's happening with this expression? b = a + (a = a + 5)

Tags: c#

```
a = 5
b = a + (a = a + 5)
```

result b = 15

Why the first 'a' do not changes after that (a = a + 5)? But why second one changes? What exactly is happening here by steps?

Comment: The first `a` is evaluated first. It being _first_ and all.

Comment: Perhabs the second line is evaluated from left to right, resulting in `b = 5 + ( 10 )`, which is `15`.

Comment: The expression is parsed left to right so a is 5 when it is first accessed

Comment: Everything aside, don't write code like that.

Comment: Reading the answers it would also be interesting to clarify `b = (a = a + 5) + a`

Comment: It seems purely academic to know why this happens which isn't bad. Regardless why, I really hope nobody is writing code like this.

Comment: @phq; `b` will have value `20`.

Comment: Shouldn't we be open to new ways of coding? Such as closures and tertiary operators?

Comment: If someone interested there is an example                   `public static int NOD(int a, int b)

        {
            while (b != 0)
                b = a % (a = b);
            return a;
        }`
It is "Greatest common divisor" function.

Comment: @zardilior - Re *Shouldn't we be open to new ways of coding?* No, not always. The right answer to this question is DON'T DO THAT, in all caps. C and C++ have a simple answer: Nasal demons might well fly out of your nose. Haskell and other function languages try to have a somewhat simpler (but ultimately wrong) answer: That's illegal. (It's ultimately wrong because of the self-referential problem. Read *Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid* for details.) Languages such as C# that try to make sense out of this are just fooling themselves. In all languages, the answer is DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: All programs should be written such that it is readable. Almost certainly you will be back and making changes before you know it. So write code such that, anyone who reads it, can easily understand the logic. Code has to be maintained over time and most certainly it will *not* be you, who is later making changes and fixing bugs! This kind of code depends on the knowledge of a resource. Most real world programs do not require any fancy work. So KISS, is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidHammen: "It's ultimately wrong because of the self-referential problem" I feel like you have to elaborate on that one. I'm not going to read a whole book to find the justification :)

Comment: @NiklasB. - Determining whether a system is somehow self-referential is akin to determining whether the program will halt.

Comment: @David So how does that relate to language design, in particular purely functional languages?

Comment: @PeterDuniho There's no need to be a smart arse. People are here to learn.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Expressions are evaluated left to right - always, regardless of grouping. So it's equivalent to:

```
a = 5;

int lhs = a; // 5
int rhs = (a = a + 5); // Increments a by 5 (i.e. a=10), and rhs=10
b = lhs + rhs; // 15
```

So after this has executed, `a` *will* be 10. But that only happens after `a` has been evaluated for the first operand of the main addition, which is why the result is 15 rather than 20.

It's really important to understand the part about evaluation order not being the same as precedence. Consider this:

```
int x = First() + Second() * Third();
```

*Precedence* means that the multiplication applies to the results of calling `Second()` and `Third()` - but `First()` is still evaluated first. In other words, this statement is equivalent to:

```
int lhs = First();
int rhs = Second() * Third();
int x = lhs + rhs;
```

See [Eric Lippert's blog post on predence, associativity and ordering](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx) for more details.

I would strongly advise against writing code like this though.

Comment: So _parens_ are not getting **higher** priority you meant? Like the OP did `(a = a + 5)`..

Comment: But, I am not really satisfied with your answer. as you explain this BY PARTS, means you evaluate this expression in two different statements (Left & Right). So, as far your answer is concerned, you are right. but the question's statement is different & EVALUATED IN SINGLE STEP.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: The parentheses are for *grouping*, not *order*. The LHS of the expression is *always* executed first, regardless of the grouping.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir: No, the whole point of the answer is that my statements are *equivalent* to the original statement. It's not like the original statement is being performed atomically in the CPU. The compiler is breaking it down into multiple steps (and even my answer could be broken down into extra steps for the intermediate addition).

Comment: Isn't the order unspecified?

Comment: @Erbureth: in C or C++ the order is unspecified, but this question isn't about those languages.

Comment: @SteveJessop do you have a citation for that? just curious.

Comment: @UmurKontacı: Do you mean about C/C++, or about C#? It's all pretty clear in the C# language specification.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of my highschool math lessons. I kept failing the tests until I learned programming, that magically enlightened me on (basic) math. So, thanks for putting a smile on my facewhile enjoying memories @JonSkeet!

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant in C/C++ since Steve has mentioned the order is unspecified in those languages

Answer (score 18):

Unlike C and C++, the order of evaluation of subexpressions are *left to right* in C#. That's why the expression

```
j= ++i + ++i ;
```

has well *defined behavior* in C# while *undefined* in C and C++.

In expression

```
b = a + (a = a + 5)
```

left `a` will be evaluated first, then `a+5` is evaluated and assigned to `a` and after addition of both evaluated subexpression, `b` will have value `15`.

Comment: In your first example, both sides of the addition equation are the same, so even if it is parsed RTL, the answer should be the same.

Comment: @BrianHannay;C standard says that: ***If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object** or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
object, **the behavior is undefined***. This makes first statement come under undefined behavior. While second statement invokes UB because C standard says: *If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
effect occurs in any of the orderings*.....

Comment: ......Just print the value of `j` after `j= ++i + ++i ;` in both C and C# and see the [effect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24735290/2455888). BTW, here is output for [C](http://ideone.com/8NWsCR) and [C#](http://ideone.com/0UTnZK).

Comment: Saying "j = ++i + ++i is undefined" means, I think, that the code could implement either increment first.  As it happens, either choice yields the same result.  But if you had "j = ++i + --i", then the result could take on different values depending on whether the increment or decrement was done first.

Comment: @user3294068: That would be correct if it were "implementation defined".  But it's _undefined_, which means the program can do anything, including crash.

Comment: @user3294068; I am not saying it my own that its undefined, but C standard says that. Read my first comment.

Answer (score 10):

The expression is always evaluated from left to right & then assigned to whatever on left hand.
As

```
  a = 5
  b = a + (a = a + 5)
\\b = 5 + (a = 5 + 5)
  b = 15
```

Comment: You said *But, I am not really satisfied with your answer* for Jon's answer. That's fine, but how does your answer is any better than Jon's answer? Also it's not clear what you're trying to say with line 3 `b = 5 + (a = 5 + 5)` At least annotate it with comment, so that it makes sense.

Comment: *"but how does your answer is any better than Jon's answer?"* - that's a trivial question. It never is!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes you are right. I comment it. And i explains only that the expression is always evaluates from left to right. and the result is assigned to operand on left of assignment statement.

Comment: Your code example isn't explaining very well. It implies that it is substituting the value of a in both parts of the expression at the same time which it isn't. In this case it doesn't matter but it might lead people to incorrectly apply the same logic to get `b = (a = a + 5) + a` leads to `b = (a = 5 + 5) + 5` in a single step which is wrong. You need to show that it evaluates the LHS fully first and then starts evaluating the right hand side by for example including `b = 5 + (a = a + 5)` as one of your intermediate steps.

Comment: I totally agree with @Chris. I'd also add `b = 5 + (a = 10)` and `b = 5 + 10 // a is now 10` as additional intermediate steps. The last step I mentioned would also clearly indicate when a's value actually changes (you could perhaps add "a is still 5" at the step before or "a was 5 up to now" at that step to make this change more clear).

Comment: yes @Chris, i want to explain the same thing as you told. i explains that the expression evaluates from left to right. and result assigns from right to left. As in case of b = a + (a = a + 5), the first 'a' is assigned first (because on left side), and in case of b = (a = a + 5) + a, the statement '(a = a + 5)' evaluates first (because on left side) & the value of 'a' is changed in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

We always work left to right the *Parens* just group parts of the sum.So just remember always go left to right. I have gone step by step below

**start with the question**

a = 5

b = a + (a = a + 5)

**So now change the first 'a' to a 5**

b = 5 + (a = a + 5)

**now lets do the sum in the *parens***

b = 5 + (a = 5 + 5)

**This gives us**

b = 5 + 10 **or you could say** b = 5 + (a = 10)

**and the answer is**

b = 15

**also now**

a = 10