# Operator precedence depends upon lanaguage or independent

Tags: php

I have seen a question on stack over flow. 
[What's happening with this expression? b = a + (a = a + 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937789/whats-happening-with-this-expression-b-a-a-a-5)

It shows the value of b will be 15. But when i run this code on Php, value of b is 20.

Why there is difference of output in php and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happens because PHP and C# differently used memory for save variables.
Read [How PHP manages variables](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/how-php-manages-variables-125644.html).
So PHP not duplicated zval memory for variable "$a" and value of $a changed when `($a = $a +5)` has been completed so we have that

```
$a = 5;
echo $a + ($a = $a + 5);  //20
```

and C# has duplicated memory for `a` variables read answer  [What's happening with this expression? b = a + (a = a + 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937789/whats-happening-with-this-expression-b-a-a-a-5).